# Need help regarding a mix of PHP and ASP .NET

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm running a Windows Server 2008 for all my ASP .NET stuff. Then I have some stuff which is still managed by WordPress as a CMS. For some reason, I believe that it's a bad thing mixing ASP .NET and ASP.NET files in the same domain (or subdomain), especially when talking about a huge project like Wordpress.

The thing is, right now we have a subdomain hosting a knowledge bank built from Wordpress with all the information we need. However, where I work they want to change that to mydomain.com/knowledge instead of knowledge.mydomain.com. This adds complexity, since mydomain.com already contains ASP .NET files.

I told them that this is probably not a good idea. Yes, it'll work, but it's not pretty. What to do? What are your suggestions?

I know this may be subjective, but all I ask is some pros and cons for mixing or not mixing up PHP and ASP .NET files in the same folder, and perhaps **some alternative solutions to the problem**.

**Note** IIS is what is running on the server.

Comment: So PHP runs on IIS as well in this scenario?

Comment: This probably belongs in another forum, since it's asking opinion.

Comment: yes, more an esoteric question..

Comment: As I marked with bold, alternative solutions is what I need.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect IIS information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's simply an issue of separation of files and folders, just map the URL to the folder.

I believe this can probably be done with Virtual Directory. "The virtual directory name becomes part of the application's URL, and users can request the URL from a browser to access content in the physical directory."

Comment: Interesting. I'll check this out and report back.

Answer (score 1):

First thing popping up to my mind, without much thought, is that you'll end up with added complexity (also from a mainteinance point of view) to instruct your web server(s) to properly handle and separate php from asp files. Having them interpreted by the wrong parser could cause quite a lot of issues; and possibly some security breaches (IE reveal source code, configuration details). Moreover implementing this might be not so trivial, depending on how your filesystem is layed out.

As for the pros of this solution, SEO purpuses is one I'm thinking of. I'm not an expert in the field, but I've read somewhere (a respectable source, anyways, which unfortunately I cannot recall right now) that keeping all (quality) content within same domain will strenghten domain authority.

As an **alternate solution**, you might play with web server modules (or proxy in front of it), so to transparently redirect requests for one kind of scripts to the host providing such specific service. You'd be giving the impression of servicing everything through a single host, whereas there'd be two separate hosts doing the (specialized) work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some URL rewrites if you have ISAPIRewrite or something but that's a bit... messy.